# Sticky position of nav change background at scroll position

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, nav, sticky

I want the `<nav>` to be fixed with the 3 numbers. When it reaches the green square, it should go OVER the numbers and stay fixed and turn red. And when you go back to the top, it should go back to it's original position and go back to green. How would I achieve this?

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.square{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp) to detect scroll and use [window.onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) to add sticky class to your element, also note that when using [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) CSS attribute value for display you should also adjust the location, I used [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate the left value, here is a working snippet:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.querySelector(".square");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 10000px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.square {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color:red;
  left: calc((100% - 100px)/2);
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
      <p>3</p>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <div class="square"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing backgroung-color, you need to look in the *animation* way, but, according the positioning, you need to add something like `top: 0` to set in what position you component will be **sticky**.